# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] When trying to write err to file in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, discord.js, fs

So I'm trying to make an error handler that sends a message saying "Oh No! There was an uncaughtException" with a text file containing the error message, but every time I try to do it, It always says this:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received function toString
```

Here is the code for the bot

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const content = err;
const file = '.\errorlog.txt';
const callback = (err) => { 
console.log("The code has failed.")
console.log(err)
setTimeout(wait, 1000); };
console.log("ERROR!!!! D:")
console.log(err)
client.login(no token for you lmao);
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready To send Error Log")
    setTimeout(wait, 1000);
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get(I dont feel comfortable sending the channel ID)
    channel.send('Oh No! There was an uncaughtException!');
    fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/textFileName.txt', toString, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(err, ' > errorlog.txt');
    });
    console.log(err)
    channel.send("Error log", {files: ['./.errorlog.txt']});
    setTimeout(shutdown, 500);
})
})

function shutdown () {
client.destroy();
}
```

I tried searching up the error and my situation, but I found nothing useful.

What I'm using:

- Nodejs v15.2.1
- Windows 10 x64
- npm 7.0.8

Thank you.

Comment: Your `./.errorlog.txt` is not exist or wrong path. Not everytime you having `errorlog.txt` as provided code

Comment: it does exist, it's literally the only file its writing to

Comment: Did you path is right

Comment: sorry if this rude, but I don't understand anything you just said :|

Comment: Watch my answer. I mean you file path maybe wrong

Comment: yes i'm pretty sure

Answer (score 0):

to send attachment files with Discord.js you can do something like :

```js
channel.send("Error log",{
  files: [{
    attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.text', // Make sure file path is right.Can try abosulte path first
    name: 'file.text'
  }]
})
```